# Return Json Using PetaPoco Dynamic & WebAPI

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, petapoco

Is it possible to use PetaPoco dynamic query to return Json in the ASP.net WebAPI?

//WebAPI Controller

```
public class BranchController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<dynamic> Get()
    {
        // Create a PetaPoco database object
        var db = new PetaPoco.Database("DefaultConnection");

        // Show all Branches
        var b = db.Query<dynamic>("SELECT * FROM Branches").ToList();

        return b;
    }

}
```

I am receiving an error

> To be XML serializable, types which inherit from IEnumerable must have an implementation of Add(System.Object)

Comment: I've never used PetaPoco, but have you tried converting returned objects to dynamic JsonObject or JsonArray instances ? http://goo.gl/BaIx5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON.Net handles this out of the box, so I Had to add a Custom Formatter.

This is the MSDN article I used to resolve the issue: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-JSONNET-with-ASPNET-b2423706

Answer (score 0):

Since PetaPoco returns a `List<dynamic>` the real answer here is *"Can WebApi return a Json from a List"*?

The answer is yes, but WebApi has a thing called [Content Negotiation](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2012/04/19/asp-net-web-api-how-content-negotiation-works.aspx) than return Json or XML based on the request.

Try requesting Json or try this for XML:

```
    // Show all Branches
    return (IEnumerable<dynamic>)db.Query<dynamic>("SELECT * FROM Branches");
```